# JavaScript closure compiler type coercion performance

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, coercion

Do compilers perform poorly with booleans converted to integers?

```
/**
 * @type {boolean}
 */
var isFirstCall = true;

handler();
handler();
handler();

function handler () {
    if (isFirstCall --> false) {
        // this runs once; isFirstCall and false were coerced to integers
    }
}
```

Comment: "Do compilers perform poorly" --- what does it exactly mean? If you're unsure on what it will be compiled to - why wouldn't you just check?

Comment: JSPerf tests may be in order - and it may depend on the JS Engine.

Comment: I don't really understand the code example, what is "-->"? Where is the coercion to integer?

Comment: `true-- === 0` next time, and `0 > false` is really `0 > 0` which is false